# Select multiple columns from inner join in Silverstripe 3.1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, silverstripe

In my events calendar module for Silverstripe 3.1, i have added some additional fields to CalendarEvent. I want to make use of these in my template, but from my researches i have seen that events are exported as being CalendarDateTime so i can't use my additional fields.

I have found that in getStandardEvents function, there is a inner join which i think is causing the problem, but i can't figure it out to join the columns from CalendarEvent

```
$list = DataList::create('CalendarDateTime')
        ->filter(array(
            'EventID' => [139, 140, 141, 143]
        ))
        ->innerJoin('CalendarEvent', "EventID = \"{CalendarEvent}\".\"ID\"")
        ->innerJoin("SiteTree", "\"SiteTree\".\"ID\" = \"{CalendarEvent}\".\"ID\"")
        ->where("Recursion != 1");
```

Note: In my code, i have some of the columns as variables, so i have written them as the values that are reffering to.
Here is the original code:

```
$list = DataList::create($datetimeClass)
        ->filter(array(
            $relation => $ids
        ))
        ->innerJoin($eventClass, "$relation = \"{$eventClass}\".\"ID\"")
        ->innerJoin("SiteTree", "\"SiteTree\".\"ID\" = \"{$eventClass}\".\"ID\"")
        ->where("Recursion != 1");
```

I have tried to add the 'CalendarEvent' as a second parameter inside DataList::create(), but no result. I have the same output.

So how can i select columns from CalendarDateTime and CalendarEvent tables ?
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a manual way:

```
$list = DB::query('SELECT * FROM "CalendarDateTime" INNER JOIN "CalendarEvent" ON "EventID" = "CalendarEvent"."ID" INNER JOIN "SiteTree" ON "SiteTree"."ID" = "CalendarEvent"."ID" WHERE "Recursion" != 1');
```

Any other solutions are welcome.